# Composition of Portland Cement before Hydration

Tags: everyday-chemistry, materials

I recently came across a question-

> Which of following chemicals is NOT found in Portland Cement?
>
> A. Di-calcium silicate
>
> B. Tri-calcium silicate
>
> C. $\ce{CaSiO3}$
>
> D. $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$

I answered D. $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$. But according to the examiner the answer is C. $\ce{CaSiO3}$

I strongly doubt that. Any pointers to credible sources/books settling this please!!

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with the site! Why do you think that the answer is not $\ce{CaSiO3}$? It will help the answerers to answer your question!

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up...as per my understanding Tri calcium phosphate is bioactive part of Cement used to reconstruction bones, like tooth filling may be...That's completely different application from Portland Cement

Comment: Calcium phosphate is an undesireable component in portland cement. One of its origins can be the usage of meat and bone meal in cement kilns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Ullmann’s Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry (sixth edition), Portland cement consists mainly of tricalcium silicate, dicalcium silicate, tricalcium aluminate, and calcium aluminoferrite.

$$
\textbf{Phase composition of Portland cement clinker} \\
\begin{array}{llll}
\hline
\text{Constituent} & \text{Formula} & \text{Content in wt %} \\
& & \text{Range} & \text{Average}\\
\hline
\text{Tricalcium silicate} & \ce{3CaO.SiO2} & 46{-}79 & 61 \\
\text{Dicalcium silicate} & \ce{2CaO.SiO2} & 5{-}30 & 15 \\
\text{Calcium aluminoferrite} & \ce{2CaO.(Al2O3,Fe2O3)} & 4{-}16 & \phantom{0}8 \\
\text{Tricalcium aluminate} & \ce{3CaO.Al2O3} & 6{-}18 & 12 \\
\text{Free calcium oxide} & \ce{CaO} & 0.1{-}4 \\
\text{Free magnesium oxide} & \ce{MgO} & 0.7{-}1.5 & \phantom{0}1.5 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Büchel, Moretto, Woditsch *Industrial Inorganic Chemistry* (second edition) lists the same six constituents as important clinker phases. This reference also includes a diagram for the three component system $\ce{CaO}$–$\ce{SiO2}$–$\ce{Al2O3}$ with composition ranges for various cement types, which shows that calcium monosilicate (CS) is not necessarily within the typical range for Portland cement.

[image: Three component system CaO–SiO2–Al2O3 with composition ranges for the hydraulic bonding agents]

Furthermore, this reference includes a table with a typical chemical analysis of a Portland cement, which shows that the $\ce{CaO}$–$\ce{SiO2}$ ratio is too high for calcium monosilicate and also indicates that small amounts of phosphate could be present:

$$
\textbf{Typical chemical composition of a Portland cement clinker} \\
\begin{array}{ll}
\hline
\ce{CaO} & 58{-}67\ \% \\
\ce{SiO2} & 16{-}26\ \% \\
\ce{Al2O3} & \phantom{0}4{-}8\ \% \\
\ce{Fe2O3} & \phantom{0}2{-}5\ \% \\
\ce{MgO} & \phantom{0}1{-}5\ \% \\
\ce{SO3} & \phantom{0}0.1{-}2.5\ \% \\
\ce{Mn2O3} & \phantom{0}0{-}3\ \% \\
\ce{P2O5} & \phantom{0}0{-}1.5\ \% \\
\ce{TiO2} & \phantom{0}0{-}0.5\ \% \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Yes, most articles talk about the main components and active compounds. What if one of the chemicals is a non-active component in trace amount. I hope some research article talks about that...Google didn't help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get it now. I found some supporting content. According to the European Standard EN 197-1 , The ratio of CaO to SiO2 shall not be less than 2.0. Also there is excess free CaO found in Cement. That must be the reason why mono-calcium silicate doesnt exist in final product.